# Powershell latest MSBuild path

Tags: powershell, msbuild

After trying a number of approaches, including what seemed an excellent suggestion at http://www.bdevuyst.com/powershell-path-msbuild-exe/, which gave me an error, I tried to break it down. Though I get the latest MSBuild registry key (14.0), I still get this error when I try to extract the path to MSBuild:

```
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\USERS\user\Desktop\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0' because it does not exist.
At C:\USERS\mtroi\Desktop\VSS_POC1_Setup.ps1:529 char:5
+     Get-ItemProperty -Path $MsBuildVersion -Name MSBuildToolsPath
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\USERS\mtroi\...lsVersions\14.0:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand

    # 32bit or 64bit local OS?
    if($ENV:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -eq "x86") 
        {$HKLMpath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\"}
    elseif($ENV:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -eq "AMD64")
        {$HKLMpath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\"}
    else
        {Write-Host "Local processor architecture not supported. Exiting installation..."; EXIT}
    # Which path (version) of local MSBuild?
    $_decSep = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;
    $MsBuild1 = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $HKLMpath | Where { $_.Name -match '\\\d+.\d+$' })
    ForEach ($build in $MsBuild1)
    {
        $Expression=$Expression+","+[System.Convert]::ToDecimal($build.Name.Substring($build.Name.LastIndexOf("\") + 1))
    }
    $MsBuildVersion = Get-ChildItem -Path $HKLMpath | Where { $_.Name -match '\\\d+.\d+$' } | 
        Sort-Object -Property  @{Expression=$Expression} -Descending | 
        Select-Object -First 1 #| Get-ItemProperty -Name MSBuildToolsPath
    Get-ItemProperty -Path $MsBuildVersion -Name MSBuildToolsPath
```

Comment: `-Path $MsBuildVersion` -> `-Path $MsBuildVersion.PSPath`

Comment: Thank you @PetSerAl. But my intent is to get just the path string so I can launch it later. In other words, I need $MsBuildVersion == "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\". I haven't found a way to extract that property from the set of "PS*" properties returned by Get-ItemProperty.